# Removing Blurb-Sidebar on Wordpress Website

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

My wordpress website constantly keeps showing this funny thing:

"Use your widget sidebars in the admin Design tab to change this little blurb here. Add the text widget to the Blurb Sidebar!"

How do I remove/hide this area?

I went to website/wp-admin/widgets.php but I am not sure how do I hide the "blurb" area. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please contact the vendor of your software to learn about your support options.

Comment: noo..that doesn't sound interesting..you mean contact Wordpress?

Comment: Sure, if you've got a problem with the software, I'm sure your feedback is welcome. Also this website here is about programming questions, not about helping you with individual issues in using a specific software. You find Wordpress support here: http://wordpress.org/support/

Comment: The `admin Design Tab` is not `widgets.php`. It is in the admin area most probably in the `Themes` section and depends on the settings for the theme you are using. Just go there and try, so your question is not about coding and I don't think it belongs here.

Comment: @hakre: Ok, please vote to close and if possible give me 1 negative vote.

Comment: @hakre as high rep user on [Wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) shouldn't such questions be posted there? Or is it off topic there as well?

Comment: @hakre et al: You may both be wrong. I've seen many loopy WordPress themes that require a good deal of hacking to work as hoped (but not intended). Hacking on WordPress is certainly a dirty business, but it could count as Step 1 of any distinguished programming career. Who know, Jack's problem may lead him to reimplement WordPress in PHP 5, and that can only be a good thing! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I do not think so, because it still is a support request in my eyes, it does not show any research or something substentially done (no offence please, this *is* fine for support, but not for serious administration as the WP.SE site has it's focus nor for *programmig* as what this site here is aout) before asking.

Comment: @IanAtkin: Which doesn't turn this into a good question that can be reasonably answered IMHO.

Comment: @hakre: research on what? I already searched for disabling Blurb area but didn't find and which is why this question exists in 1st place. This isn't a support request. This has to be solved by me.

Comment: @hakre You're probably right.

Comment: @hakre: Ian has already answered it and it fits my needs and it's already working.

Comment: @Jack: Well, mine is only a single opinion, you don't need to stress this too much. Please don't feel offended by my comments, I just wanted to give you some friendly hints and suggestions how to improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably aware that WordPress uses themes to provide for different use cases and (a)esthetics. The sidebar in question is undoubtedly a feature of the theme you have chosen to use. Each theme has a series of templates to provide for certain functionality. The themes live in...

```
/wp-content/themes/[your_theme]/
```

There will be a PHP file for each page type. What you want to do can be done in two different ways.

1. Edit the PHP file, and remove the `DIV` that renders the sidebar you wish to remove.
2. Edit the CSS file and set the `DIV` in question to `display:none`.

Both methods may have the knock-on effect of simply removing the offending area without adjusting the rest of the page content. You will likely need to set any adjacent `DIV`s to `width:100%` or similar.

Comment: +1 Thanks but you shouldn't be answering this because this is off topic as per hekre

Comment: I think that's subjective. Since the answer requires diving into PHP or CSS, I believe it's not off-topic at all.